# Gridster2 implementation

Tags: angular

I implement Gridster2 in the angular project, basically following documentation.
https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2

[image]

Problem is that as soon as I import **GridsterModule** and save code, without any change in component & HTML I got a compilation error.
[image]

It looks to me that problem is somewhere on the Gridster side.
What I'm doing wrong?
Any help is welcome :)

Comment: is rxjs greater than `7.5.6`(gridster is expecting this version) in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem was the old version or **rxjs** as @Naren Murali mentioned. Thank you, Naren!

> **Rxjs package must be at least 7.5.5**

```
"rxjs": "^7.5.5"
```